# Abstraction over single c++ object and std::pair of objects using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, abstraction

Assume the following template construction:

```
enum class ENUM {SINGLE, PAIR};
// General data type
template<ENUM T, class U>class Data;
// Partially specialized for single objects
template<class U>Data<ENUM::SINGLE, U> : public U {
  // Forward Constructors, ...
};
// Partially specialized for pairs of objects
template<class U>Data<ENUM::PAIR, U> : public std::pair<U,U> {
  // Forward Constructors, ...
};
```

In my code I want to be able to write something like

```
template<ENUM T>someMethod(Data<T, SomeClass> data) {
  for_single_or_pair {
    /*
     * Use data as if it would be of type SomeClass
     */
  }
}
```

which should do the same as the combination of the following methods:

```
template<>someMethod(Data<ENUM::SINGLE, SomeClass> data) {
  data.doStuff();
}

template<>incrementData(Data<ENUM::PAIR, SomeClass> data) {
  data.first.doStuff();
  data.second.doStuff();
}
```

I.e. I want to be able to use a pair of objects (of the same type) as if it would be a single object. Of course I could reimplement the methods of a type `T` for `Data<ENUM::PAIR, T>` (see the answer of dau_sama) which for the given example would look like:

```
template<>Data<ENUM::PAIR, SomeClass> : public std::pair<SomeClass, SomeClass> {
  doStuff() {
    this->first.doStuff();
    this->second.doStuff();
  }
};
```

But I would have to do this for many methods and operators and many different types, although the methods and operators would all look like this example.

The syntax of the solution may be very different from what I wrote above, this is just to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I would prefer a solution without macros, but could also live with that.

Can such an abstraction be realized in C++11?

The reasons I want to do this are

1. I do not have to specialize templated methods that shall work for  `ENUM::Single` and `ENUM::PAIR` when all differences between the specializations would math the pattern above (avoid a lot of code duplication).
2. The same pattern is occuring very often in my code and I could avoid implementing workarounds in many places, which would be almost identical in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create a template method `applyMethod`. Here is a complete example. I used an `Executor` class containing only one static method because I could not find a better way to process methods taking any types of parameters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum ENUM {SINGLE, PAIR};
// General data type
template<ENUM T, class U>class Data {
};
// Partially specialized for single objects
template<class U>
class UData : public Data<ENUM::SINGLE, U>, public U {
  // Forward Constructors, ...
public:
        UData(const U& u): U(u) {};
};
// Partially specialized for pairs of objects
template<class U>
class PData : public Data<ENUM::PAIR, U>, public std::pair<U,U> {
  // Forward Constructors, ...
public:
        PData(const U& u1, const U& u2): std::pair<U, U>(u1, u2) {};
};

template <class U, typename... P>
class Executor {
        Executor() = delete;
public:
        template<void (U::*M)(P... params)>
        static void applyMethod(Data<ENUM::SINGLE, U> &data, P ...params) {
                UData<U>& ud= reinterpret_cast<UData<U>& >(data);
                U& u = static_cast<U&>(ud);
                (u.*M)(params...);
        }
        template<void (U::*M)(P... params)>
        static void applyMethod(Data<ENUM::PAIR, U> &data, P ...params) {
                PData<U>& pd = reinterpret_cast<PData<U>& >(data);
                (pd.first.*M)(params...);
                (pd.second.*M)(params...);
        }
};

class X {
        std::string name;
public:
        X(const std::string& name): name(name) { };

        void doStuff(void) {
                std::cout << "DoStuff : " << name << std::endl;
        }
        void doStuff(int i) {
                std::cout << "DoStuff : " << name << " - " << i << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
        X x1("x1");
        X x2("x2");
        X x3("x3");

        UData<X> data1(x1);
        PData<X> data2(x2, x3);

        Executor<X>::applyMethod<&X::doStuff>(data1);
        Executor<X, int>::applyMethod<&X::doStuff>(data2, 12);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed you created the classes `UData` and `PData`, so that I cannot work directly with a `Data<T,SomeClass> data`, i.e. I cannot call `Executor<T, SomeClass>::applyMethod<&SomeClass::doStuff>(data)`, unless `T` is actually determined in the code already. So I still cannot avoid the specialization of `someMethod`, can I?

Comment: @user2296653 : yes you can ! I've just found a way where `Executor` class is unique and uses correct method depending on the actual data passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a common method to your classes

```
template<class U>
Data<ENUM::SINGLE, U> : public U {
  // Forward Constructors, ...
  void handle() {
    //do some specific handling for this type 
    return;
  }
};
```

Now someMethod will just call the right "handle" and it'll automatically switch between the two

```
template<typename T>
someMethod(T& data) {
  data.handle();
}

//If you want to bind your function to some other name, you could
//create a functor that calls someMethod with the arguments passed in _1
//I haven't tested it, there might be some syntax problems with the way you pass in the function name
auto someOtherMethod = std::bind (someMethod, _1);
```

If your type doesn't implement a handle method, you'll have a nasty compilation error. If you want to provide a default implementation and avoid a compilation error, there is a common pattern called SFINAE (Substitution failure is not an error) that does exactly that.

Comment: This is not precisely what I wanted to achieve (see my edit).

Comment: then what you could do, is to have a custom method instead of the operator++. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I noticed that my question was not precise enough. Thus, your updated answer is unfortunately still not what I am looking for (see my EDIT 2).

Comment: check my edit! I could argue though, that if you have several methods with different names, all doing the same thing, there isa design problem. It may be that you're tied on a legacy API that you can't touch though.. that's a different story :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for producing so much confusion. I think we were disagreeing on which part I want to abstract away. I rewrote the examples and added a paragraph why your solution is not what I am looking for (it is not general enough).

Comment: If you need to switch between different types you always have to provide a specialization, hence you'll have to write a method somewhere that handles that case. If all you want to do is call the identical methods, from different types, you could have a templated friend function. Or you could switch between different types using a traits class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the solution to that from Serge Ballesta, using lambdas.

```
#include <functional>

template<ENUM T, class U>void for_single_or_pair(
    Data<T, U>& data,
    std::function<void(U&)> function);

template<class U>void for_single_or_pair(
    Data<ENUM::SINGLE, U>& data,
    std::function<void(U&)> function) {
  function(data);
}

template<class U>void for_single_or_pair(
    Data<ENUM::PAIR, U>& data,
    std::function<void(U&)> function) {
  function(data.first);
  function(data.second);
}
```

Usage:

```
template<ENUM T>someMethod(Data<T, SomeClass> data) {
  for_single_or_pair(data,[](SomeClass& someObject) {
    // Play around with someObject in any way
  });
}
```

In this way additionally to use member methods of SomeClass, the data can be used in any other way.

I would be happy about comments to this solution (and if it could be generalized to use more than one Data inside the for_single_or_pair method).